# Test on Hex value

Tags: java

I want to catch this Exception and i want to do some treatement in the catch block here's the code :

```
  try {
root.setText(page.getText(field.getLine() + repetition,
                          field.getColumn(),
                          field.getLength()));
  } catch (org.jdom2.IllegalDataException e) {
// ignore: some lines can be empty and cannot
// be a valid XML character so we skip them

String invalidStr = page.getText(field.getLine() + repetition, field.getColumn(),field.getLength());

  }
```

Here's the error printed when i use e.printStackTrace(); method :

```
org.jdom2.IllegalDataException: The data "
                                      " is not legal for a JDOM character content: 0x000c is not a legal XML character.
at org.jdom2.Text.setText(Text.java:182)
```

So How to make a test on the value of the character 0x000c:

```
    String invalidStr = page.getText(field.getLine() + repetition, field.getColumn(),field.getLength());
    if (invalidStr.equals(???)) {
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this works for you (invalidStr.indexOf(0x000C) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (invalidStr.indexOf(0x000C) >= 0) ...
```

Or

```
if (invalidStr.indexOf('\u000C') >= 0) ...
```

Or

```
if (invalidStr.contains("\u000C")) ...
```

(using a [Unicode escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3))

Comment: Thanks for the link. That make sense now. I am confused due to two reasons. 1 OP's String contains  hex character ( usually it converts to char ) 2. OP wasnt accepting your solution long time :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "indexOf" method on the string object:

```
 String invalidStr = page.getText(field.getLine() + repetition, field.getColumn(),field.getLength());
    if (invalidStr.indexOf((char)0x000C) >= 0) {
    }
```

Comment: There is no `String.contains(char)` method.